# How to delete a cookie at the click of logout in Asp.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a asp.net MVC3 Application with two users Admin and General.Cookies is saved for both the users.
Below is how my cookies is saved.

```
 Cookie.setCookie(No,DOB,User);
```

Have a class Cookie with the method setCookie

```
 public static void setCookie(int No,DateTime DOB,string User)
        {
            HttpCookie MyCookie= new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
            MyCookie["No"] = No;
            MyCookie["DOB"] = DOB;
            MyCookie["User"] = User;

            MyCookie.Expires.Add(new TimeSpan(0,30,0));

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(MyCookie);
        }
```

Above is my Setcookie code.

```
MyCookie.Expires.Add(new TimeSpan(0,30,0));will give the default expiry time to 30 minutes.
```

What im trying is when the user click Logout  the cookie should get completely cleared and the user should not be able to navigate to any of the Authenticated sections of the site.
Also i have tried this but no use

```
MyCookie.Expires.Add(-1);
```

But i have tried that in my SetCookie method.How can i make the cookies cleared when the user clicks Logout.
Also i have tried creating a Logout Method in Cookie Class like below:

```
  public static bool logout()
        {

            HttpCookie reqCookies = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"];
            reqCookies.Expires.AddDays(-1);
            return true;
        }
```

Here im Trying to use the already saved cookie and Expire it by setting `.AddDays(-1);`
And im using if `cookie.Logout()==true`  and redirecting it to my Home.
But it is giving me following error on RunTime
**The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.
Parameter name: value**

Any suggestions/guidance on how can i achieve my target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a jquery cookie script for that.

```
<a href="" onclick="removeCookie();">logout button</a>

function removeCookie(){
$.cookie('cookiename', '');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

To clear a cookie in ASP.NET, you need to set a new cookie with the same name with an expired time.

Comment: Created a New Cookie and trying to Set .AddDays(-1)
  public static bool logout()
        {
            HttpCookie MyCookie= new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
            MyCookie.Expires.AddDays(-1);
            return true;
        }
Same error continues
The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime. Parameter name: value

Comment: Try `MyCookie.Expries = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1)`. `DateTime` is an immuable type so what you do is just get a new time - and it's overflow with an exception thrown.

Comment: Was missing a minor thing.
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(reqCookies);
Just had to Add the cookie again

Thanks for replies